# Bluetooth activating on wake-up from suspend & reboot

Tags: bluetooth, suspend

Bluetooth is reactivating each time without prompt (suspend or reboot), I have to switch it off manually each time too. I don't like it: that's a potential security breach and a loss of time. Why isn't there an option to switch it off by default as of boot/suspend in settings?
Machine is legacy MBP 17" 2,1

Comment: This happens to me in `Elementary OS 6` version. @Lurch, can you add version information about Elementary OS you are experiencing the issue, please? As Elementary delivery new versions time by time, it's useful for something browsing this stack to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try disabling the kernel module `sudo modprobe -r btusb` that should stop it.

You can enable again with `sudo modprobe btusb`

Comment: Ok, I have it does solve the issue successfully. Thanks.

Comment: It did, but the bluetooth indicator disappeared from the system tray - only temporarily though: now it displays again, and is again on by default.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That is because this unloads the Bluetooth driver at a low level, I'm guessing you are happy to work around this, I don't use it in the same way as yourself, I use it when Bluetooth has failed after waking from a system sleep, as it's also a good way to revive the BT system. I always have a terminal open so I guess perhaps it's more convenient for myself, but I don't otherwise know how to make it stop turning back on all the time.

Comment: True, on each boot it reactivates. Still on dual boot and recently a lot of updates require rebooting so it always turns on. Isn't there a way to deactivate it for I don't use it.

Comment: You can permanently remove the module. It's possible to get it again later.

Comment: Thank you that is useful. How do you do so?